# Using string builder and array to in a loop java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Im trying to use a string builder to append both the first file with its location then new line second file with its location etc. How do I do this? Whats the correct syntax? Whats wrong with my below loop?

```
@Override
public List<FileUpload> uploadFile(MultipartFile[] files, String windowsUsername, String number) {
List<FileUpload> uploadList = new ArrayList<FileUpload>();
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {

                FileUpload result = itsmFileService.uploadAttachment(file, number);


                uploadList.add(result);     



        }
        String supportCallID;
        supportCallID = this.getSupportCallIDForTicketNumber(number);

int i = 0;
            for (FileUpload loopLocation : uploadList){
                notesSection = uploadList.get(i).getLocation();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(notesSection);
                sb.toString();
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Where is your StringBuilder?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Put `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` before the `for` loop .

Comment: get the error notesSection cant be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new StringBuilder everytime the loop is run. Try the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (FileUpload loopLocation : uploadList){
     string notesSection = uploadList.get(i).getLocation();

     sb.append(notesSection);
}

sb.toString();
```

Comment: The variable was missing a data type. I added string and it ok. How do i append the file + the location for each itteration?

Comment: My filename is in my array uploadList, and my location in notesSection for each itteration, how do i append it together then output it outside the loop?